# Net Core Identity - Ask user for missing information / ask for Ts & Cs acceptance, on External Sign Up

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

**What am I trying to achieve?**

I want to redirect the user to a page when he/she's signing up with e.g. Google or Facebook when any of the information is missing. I would also like to ask user for the acceptance of the GDPR related stuff.

**Background**

I am using a quick start from the IdentityServer4 which is incorporating Net Core Identity with a nice quick start UI and it is handling user registration, when user is not found after hitting callback from external provider.

When a user is registering locally, there is no issue - all data is validated as expected, so I do not have any issues, but I cannot find the way to somehow get in the middle of the signup when user is registering through the external provider.

Not sure if it matters in this context, but I need it in the auth service which is using IdentityServer4.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need it in the auth service"? Could you please share which quick start you are using?

Comment: I mean service like microservice, not app service. By auth service I mean closed microservice which server users and IdentityServer.
Starter: is4aspid

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the quick start project template, you should be able to hook into the external login callback before the user is created.
See the [docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signin_external_providers.html) and an [example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/5021b7b0f75bbb6a001f33d97d64ae0bf2a683c6/Quickstart/Account/ExternalController.cs#L110).